# Frame with CornerRadius doesn't turn out rounded

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to construct a circle around a label with some text in it.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0,40,0,0">
    <Label Text="Your total score is" FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource FontBold-Bold}"/>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="30" OutlineColor="#03A9F4" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <Label Text="57%" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the frame is not turning out as a circle. No matter how much I increase the `CornerRadius` property, the corners remain the same.

Note, the `Frame` turns out as a circle on Android.

Comment: Well because its not possible no matter how much radius you increase it will never be a circle you cannot turn a rectangle to a circle

Comment: So, what confuses me, is that i'm allowed to set a `CornerRadius`, I mean, the corner radius not even rounding the corners.

Comment: Let me just refer to this: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99509/how-make-a-circle-label

Comment: Corner radius means the circular border radius it has nothing to do with forming Circles of any kind

Comment: you are not right. On Android it renders the Frame as a circle.

Comment: Okay great what exactly did you do